# Circle - Circle collision not accurate

Tags: python, collision-detection, physics

**EDIt: I have just removed the other methods we have verified to be correct as the question seemed a bit long and those methods seemed to be extraneous.**

I have a circle class which has the following attributes: center, radius, old position, acceleration, mass, and restitution.

I then apply impulse resolution as per this link: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331.

Here is the code, implementing that, along with my velocity verlet implementation (this is necessary as it explains why I change the values of the old positions of the circles near the end of the impulseScalar method):

```
def doVerletPosition(self):
    diffPos = (self.center).subtract(self.oldPos)
    aggregatePos = diffPos.add(self.center)
    ATT = (self.accel).scalarMult(dt**2)
    e = ATT.add(aggregatePos)
    return e

def doVerletVelocity(self):
    deltaD = ((self.center).subtract(self.oldPos))
    return deltaD.scalarMult(1/dt)


def impulseScalar(self,other):                                                                           

    isCollision = self.collisionDetection(other)
    collisionNormal = isCollision[0]

    if(isCollision[1] == True):

        relativeVelocity = (other.doVerletVelocity()).subtract(self.doVerletVelocity())
        normDirecVel = relativeVelocity.dotProduct(collisionNormal)

        restitution = -1-(min(self.restitution,other.restitution))

        numerator = restitution * normDirecVel

        impulseScalar = numerator/(self.invMass + other.invMass)

        impulse = collisionNormal.scalarMult(impulseScalar)

        selfVel = (self.doVerletVelocity()) 
        otherVel = other.doVerletVelocity()

        selfVelDiff = impulse.scalarMult(self.invMass)
        otherVelDiff = impulse.scalarMult(other.invMass)

        selfVel = selfVel.subtract(selfVelDiff)
        otherVel = otherVel.subtract(otherVelDiff)

        self.oldPos = (self.center).subtract(selfVel)
        other.oldPos = (other.center).subtract(otherVel)
```

It would help if you accepted the vector methods as correct on face value, and I think that they are named well enough to allow you to figure out what they do, however I can paste them in aswell.

My main problem is that when I run this, it registers that a collision has happened, yet the values position of the second circle do not change. How would I go about fixing this, as it seems that I am implementing the calculations correctly.

The values of the first and second circle is:

```
center = Vector(0,0)
radius = 3
oldPos = Vector(0,0)
accel = Vector(0,0)
mass = 1
restitution = 0.5

center2 = Vector(0,4.2)
radius2 = 1
oldPos2 = Vector(0,4.21)
accel2 = Vector(0,-1)
mass2 = 1
restitution2 = 0.7
```

What it returns is here: (it returns the position of the centers)

```
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.1896
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.178800000000001
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.167600000000001
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.1560000000000015
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.144000000000002
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.131600000000002
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.118800000000003
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.1056000000000035
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.092000000000004
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.078000000000005
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.063600000000005
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.048800000000006
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.033600000000007
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.018000000000008
0.0      0.0     0.0     4.002000000000009
0.0      0.0     0.0     3.9856000000000096
INTERSECTION
0.0      0.0     0.0     3.9688000000000105
INTERSECTION
0.0      0.0     0.0     3.9516000000000115
INTERSECTION
0.0      0.0     0.0     3.9340000000000126
```

So when it prints INTERSECTION, surely, the stationary circle must change position, if the impulseScalar method is correct, (as it seems to be (as it follows what is said on that link).

Even if I let it run for longer, the stationary circle still does not move.

Comment: Is the issue that `AABBintersection` is returning True when you expect it to return False? If so you should show the code for it. If not can you clarify the exact problem?

Comment: I probably should have included this in the main part as well, but the collision detection things work correctly, for example, if there is a still circle with radius 1 at the origin, and another with radius 3 falling from some height, it says that there is an intersection when the falling circle's center is at roughly (0,4), yet the second circle does not gain any velocity from the collision and just stays at (0,0).

Comment: So it seems the problem is `impulseScalar`? What are the values of self and other when you see the problem? What is the expected result in that case? What is the actual result?

Comment: Have you managed to see the error in my ways?

Comment: Do now worry, I have solved it. The key was to put the impulsescalar method before making the oldPos = currentPos, and the currentPos = newPos after calling the doVerletVelocity method.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with operations with negative numbers. Maybe your are changing values in a way you don't want due to that. Use sqrt everywhere.